# Multiple controls in the aggregation binding using factory function

Tags: javascript, data-binding, sapui5, aggregation

I want to include multiple controls in the `items` aggregation of the `VBox` control.

```
var title = new sap.m.Title({text: "Name"});
var nameInput = new sap.m.Input();
var nameText = new sap.m.Text();

var layout = new sap.m.VBox({
    items: {
        path: "/",
        factory: function(sId, oContext) {
            var type = oContext.getProperty("type");
            if (type) {
                 return [title, nameInput];
            } else {
                 return [title, nameText];
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I want to add `title` and `nameInput` in the `VBox` when there is something in the `type` attribute and `title` and `nameText` when the `type` is empty or undefined. But it is returning an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: o.setBindingContext is not a function
```

I am not sure why is this happening. It works when we return only single control in the factory function, but not the array. Does anyone has any clue how to return multiple controls in the aggregation binding using factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory function is supposed to return just one control instance, not an array. When I need multiple controls in one VBox item then I'd probably use a separate xml Fragment (e.g. another VBox or HBox) which in turn has many appropriate controls within.